# Связной список

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Начал изучать связные списки, возникли проблемки! Пользователь должен заполнять список, пока не захочет выйти! И перед каждым новым заполнением пользователю показывают все данные, которые он ввел, но у меня функция шоу показывает только то, что пользователь ввел самый первый раз!
Помогите "хакеру". ))

```
#include "stdafx.h"

struct STRUCT
{

    string Name;
    int Age;
    STRUCT *pNext;
    STRUCT *pPrev;
};
STRUCT *pHead;

void Addlist(int ageParam,string nameParam,int element)
{

    STRUCT *node=new STRUCT;
    node->Age=ageParam;
    node->Name=nameParam;
    if (pHead == NULL)
    {
        node->pNext=node;
        node->pPrev=node;
        pHead=node;
    }
    else
    {
        STRUCT *p=pHead;
        for (int i=element; i > 1; i--)
            p=p->pNext;
        p->pPrev=p=node;
        node->pPrev=p->pPrev;
        node->pPrev=node;
    }
    cout << "Element was add" <<endl;
}

void DeleteList (int position)
{

    if (pHead == NULL)
        cout << "List is empty" <<endl;
    if (pHead ==pHead->pNext)
    {
        delete pHead;
        pHead=NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        STRUCT *a=pHead;
        for (int i=position; i > 1; i--)
            a=a->pNext;
        if (a == pHead)
            pHead=a->pNext;
        a->pPrev->pNext=a->pNext;
        a->pNext->pPrev=a->pPrev;
        delete a;
    }
    cout << "Element was delete!" <<endl;
}

void show()
{

    if (pHead == NULL)
        cout << "List is empty!"<<endl;
    else
    {
        STRUCT * a=pHead;
        cout << "Your list: " <<endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "The name and age of the person: ";
            cout <<a->Name<<' ';
            cout <<a->Age<<endl;
            a=a->pNext;
        } while (a !=pHead);
    }

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    string tName;
    int tAge=0;
    int exit=0;
    int index=0;

    while (exit != 1)
    {
        cout << "index= " <<index <<endl;
        cout << "1-Yes, 2-No"<<endl;
        cout << "Do you want exit from program?: " <<endl;
        cin >> exit;
        if (exit == 1)
            break;

        cout << "Enter name of the person: ";
        cin >>tName;
        cout << "Enter age of this person: ";
        cin >>tAge;
        Addlist(tAge,tName,index);
        show();
        index++;

    }
    DeleteList (0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы же сами пишете

```
 p->pPrev=p=node;
 node->pPrev=p->pPrev;
 node->pPrev=node;
```

в Addlist.

Т.е. получаете

```
p = node;
```

и дальше по сути `node->pPrev = node`.

Так не пойдет. Для вставки `node` после `p`:

```
 node->pNext = p->pNext;
 node->pPrev = p;  // установили линки в node
 // установили линки на node
 p->pNext = node;  // в предыдущем
 node->pNext->pPrev = node; // в следующем
```

порядок присваиваний важен

(не проверял, но, надеюсь, не ошибся).

--

Да, и лучше явно указать, что Вы делаете **циклический** двусвязный (или двухсвязный(?)) список.

Comment: Спасибо большое.))) Все работает.)))